# Closed infinite dimensional linear subspace of $L^p((0,1))$ consisting of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $1 \le p < +\infty$. Construct a closed infinite-dimensional linear subspace of $L^p((0,1))$ consisting of continuous functions.

I tried the set of all polynomials on $(0,1)$, but polynomials are dense in $L^p$, so it's not closed. Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that such a subspace even exists ?

Comment: An idea: try the space of continuous functions which are piecewise linear on each interval $[1/(n+1), 1/n]$.

Comment: Note that by http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/727274/finite-dimensional-subspace-of-c0-1 it is impossible for this subspace to consist entirely of *bounded* functions.

Comment: @Bass, yes I'm sure that it exists.

Comment: @Nate, in your linked question, the domain is $[0,1]$, and the hint I'm given is the open property of domain is important.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be the hat function on $[0,1]$, that's is $h(x) = 2\max(0, 1 - |2x-1|)$. For $n\in \mathbb N$ let 
$$ h_n(x) = 2^n h\left( 2^{n}x-1 \right). $$ Then, consider the subspace
$$ S = \left\{  \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nh_n \mid a \in \ell^1 \right\}.$$

Actually $S$ is isometric isomorph to $\ell^1$.

Comment: Sorry, what is hut function, I can't find it by google. How is $h$ defined on $(0,1/2)$ and $(1/2,1)$?

Comment: @Philo it was a typo. It should be hat function. Sorry.

Comment: @Philo: Presumably one assumes it will be linear on those intervals, but it really doesn't matter that much.  The main point is that it's zero outside $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Philo I add the definition of the hat function. I hope it is more clear now.