# how to show that $C[0,1]$ is not a Hilbert space with respect to any inner product

Tags: functional-analysis

Show that the space $C[0, 1]$ of real-valued continuous functions on the
unit interval $[0, 1]$ with the sup norm
$$
\|f\|=\sup\{|f(x)|:\ x\in[0,1]\}
$$
is not a Hilbert space  with respect to any  inner  product .

My attempts:  as I have to find a Cauchy sequence  $(f_n)_n$ which converges to a function $f$ which is not continuous, but I can't construct such a sequence $(f_n)_n$.

Comment: You won't ever find a non-convergent Cauchy sequence in that space, because it is indeed Banach. You must prove that it is not a *Hilbert* space

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Any norm coming from an inner product satisfies the parallelogram identity. If for instance you take $f(x)=x$, $g(x)=1$, then 
$$
\|f+g\|^2+\|f-g\|^2=5,
$$
while
$$
2\|f\|^2+2\|g\|^2=4.
$$

Comment: thanks alots @Martin Argerami

Answer (score 8):

It suffices to show that [the parallelogram law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law) is not satisfied. Take $f(x)=x$, $x\in[0,1]$, and $g(x)=1$, $x\in[0,1]$. Then $2(\|f\|_\infty^2+\|g\|_\infty^2)=4$, but $\|f+g\|_\infty^2+\|f-g\|_\infty^2=5$.

Comment: thanks alots @dietrich Burde

Answer (score 4):

There is a theorem that says that a norm $(X,\|.\|)$ comes from an inner product if and only if the parallellogram law is satisfied for all elements in $X$:
$$ 2\|x\|^2+2\|y\|^2 = \|x+y\|^2+\|x-y\|^2.$$

Comment: thanks abcdef,,